# Unable to down the docker-compose files separately or in different sequence

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose, yaml, hyperledger-fabric

Hey there I'm new to docker-compose and today I encoutered a strange issue. I have two docker-compose files located inside different folders.
This is the folder structure.

```
|__compose
|   |__compose-ca1.yaml
|__compose2
|   |__compose-ca2.yaml
|__networkUp.sh
|__networkDown.sh
```

---

This is the compose-ca1.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  test:
    name: fabric_test

services:

  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:17054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
      - "17054:17054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/org1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
      - test
```

---

This is the compose-ca2.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  test:
    name: fabric_test

services:

  ca_org2:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    labels:
      service: hyperledger-fabric
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_OPERATIONS_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:18054
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
      - "18054:18054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/org2:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org2
    networks:
      - test
```

---

Here is the networkUp.sh file code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

COMPOSE_CA_FILES="-f compose/compose-ca1.yaml -f compose2/compose2-ca.yaml"
docker-compose $COMPOSE_CA_FILES up -d
```

---

Here is the networkDown.sh file code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

COMPOSE_CA_FILES="-f compose/compose-ca1.yaml -f compose2/compose2-ca.yaml"
docker-compose $COMPOSE_CA_FILES down --volumes --remove-orphans
```

---

when I execute these two files, containers up successfully and down successfully. but lets say if I change the networkDown.sh file code from this

```
COMPOSE_CA_FILES=" -f compose/compose-ca1.yaml -f compose2/compose-ca2.yaml "
```

to this

```
COMPOSE_CA_FILES=" -f compose2/compose-ca2.yaml  -f compose/compose-ca1.yaml"
```

I get the follwing errors, and the containers won't stop.

```
Removing network fabric_test
ERROR: error while removing network: network fabric_test id f4.......
```

It means if I don't follow the same sequence for the files, while docker-compose up and docker-compose down, I get the error. Also, if I down the first compose file in the sequence i.e `compose/compose-ca1.yaml`, separately through docker-compose then the other automatically gets down. If I put both (compose-ca1.yaml and compose-ca2.yaml) in the same folder like this

```
|__compose
|   |__compose-ca1.yaml
|   |__compose-ca2.yaml
|__networkUp.sh
|__networkDown.sh
```

and updates the path in networkUp.sh and networkDown.sh then the issue gets resolved. My question is why in the above case it's behaving differently.